# Event receiver not firing on item added via email

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, email

I have a list that have been configure to receive incoming email. I also create event receiver for that list (on itemAdded and on itemAdding).

The problem is, my event receiver not executed when SharePoint automatically create new item via email. Any clue for this strange behavior?

Comment: Is ItemUpdated triggered?

Comment: No event triggered when adding via email. When I add item via UI, all event are triggered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that you use the wrong event receiver.

Use the [SPEmailEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver%28v=office.14%29.aspx). This is the event you are looking for.

Tip: If you want to debug your custom EmailEventReceiver, you have to attach your debugger to the ows process (not the w3wp) and you have to reset the Sharepoint Timer Service after deployment. - it costed me 3 days to figure this out. 
[See here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/11/email-received-event-receiver-requires-a-sharepoint-timer-reset/)