# SharePoint 2010 Parse Multiline Column

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, email

I have a SharePoint 2010 announcement list setup to accept incoming emails. There is data in the body field that I need to extract(Parse) ... such as the member ID and the Date/Time field. Can anyone provide any direction on solving this issue as the OOB workflow is very limited on string manipulation.  Thanks

---- Sample Body Column Below ------

Impact Details
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam,

Member ID:  15495

Currency:  (US)

Location:  Fargo, ND

Date/Time Check In:  Nov 27 2014  8:00AM (ET)

Comments:  This is a new member with platinum status

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craig,

You can use [SPEmailEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx) to parse the email body..

> Tip: If you want to debug your custom EmailEventReceiver, you have to
>   attach your debugger to the ows process (not the w3wp) and you have to
>   reset the Sharepoint Timer Service after deployment. - it costed me 3
>   days to figure this out. [See
>   here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/11/email-received-event-receiver-requires-a-sharepoint-timer-reset/)

Reference:

[Event receiver not firing on item added via email](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/event-receiver-not-firing-on-item-added-via-email)

Comment: Thanks Arsalan for your prompt response and based on my research ... your answer appears to be the correct answer that will produce a solution to my problem!
 ........ But, As I failed to mention, I am new to SharePoint with only SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Designer 
in my toolchest. It doesn't appear I will be able to solve this problem with the tools I have available. Will Visual Studio be required to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes you will need Visual Studio to develop this Event Receiver..